# How to show that for any real numbers $x,y,z$ $|x|+|y|+|z|\le|x+y-z|+|y+z-x|+|z+x-y|?$

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that for any real numbers $x,y,z$$$|x|+|y|+|z|\le|x+y-z|+|y+z-x|+|z+x-y|?$$

I'm don't know how to split RHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $x=a+b$, $y=b+c$, $z=c+a$. Then the following equivalent inequality is clear.

$$|a+b|+|b+c|+|c+a|\le 2|a|+2|b|+2|c|$$

Comment: How do we know that the first substitution is possible?

Comment: @Horse You can solve explicitly for a general formula that expresses $a,b,c$ in terms of $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 4):

By Triangle Inequality we have: $$|x+y-z|+|y+z-x|\ge |(x+y-z)+(y+z-x)|=|2y|=2|y|\hspace{0.5cm} ...(1)$$

Similarly, we have:
$$|y+z-x|+|z+x-y|\ge 2|z|\hspace{0.5cm} ...(2)$$
$$|x+y-z|+|y+z-x|\ge 2|x|\hspace{0.5cm} ...(3)$$

Therefore, by adding $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ we have: $$2(|x+y-z|+|y+z-x|+|z+x-y|)\ge 2(|x|+|y|+|z|)$$ $$\implies |x+y-z|+|y+z-x|+|z+x-y|\ge |x|+|y|+|z|$$ $$\implies |x|+|y|+|z|\le |x+y-z|+|y+z-x|+|z+x-y|.$$

Answer (score 0):

By the Triangle Inequality, the sums, by twos, of the terms on the right-hand side are $\ge$, respectively, than $2|y|$, $2|z|$, and $2|x|$.